# Can I explicitly specify $0 before running a Perl script?

Tags: perl, bash, shell, unix

I have a Perl wrapper script, `wrapper`, which `exec`'s another tool after setting some environment variables. The tools which the wrapper may invoke are symlinked to `wrapper`, and it dynamically determines the tool which has symlinked to it by evaluating `basename($0)`. Here's a contrived example to illustrate:

```
[/tmp]$ cat wrapper
#!/usr/bin/perl    
use File::Basename;

$ENV{'CUSTOM_ENVIRONMENT'} = '1';

my $scriptName = basename($0);
exec("scripts/${scriptName}");

[/tmp]$ chmod +x wrapper
[/tmp]$ cat scripts/foo
#!/bin/sh
echo "foo"

[/tmp]$ ln -s wrapper foo
[/tmp]$ ./foo 
foo
```

I would like to avoid needing the dummy `foo` symlink and explicitly set `$0` before invoking `wrapper` directly. **Is it possible to explicitly set `$0` before invoking a Perl script?**

I know I can assign to `$0` from *within* `wrapper`, but I'd like to set the value of `$0` to be used *before* I invoke `wrapper`, so I can spoof the file name that Perl thinks is being run.

I've scanned through [`perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) and [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) but haven't found anything.

Comment: Could You describe a little bit more details about what You would like to do? The caller should be present in the system, so either a hard- or symlink or an alias or rather a bash function has to be defined to be able to call from prompt. So if You do want to create symlink, you should define alias or a function in .bash_profile (or alike) or pass an argument to `wrapper` and call it as `wrapper foo` (or similar). But maybe I misinterpreted your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible hack:

```
perl -e '$0="something_else"; do "/path/to/wrapper"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a wrapper wrapper:

```
open (my $wrapper, "<", "wrapper") or die("$!");
my $c = '$0 = "SPOOF";'.join("", <$wrapper>);
close ($wrapper);
eval $c;
```